# How to get uuid.location in .vmx file from guest OS

Tags: python, shell, vmware

As I know that the value of uuid.location in .vmx file is a unique identifier for each virtual machine, so I want to use this value for licensing my application, but I have a problem of getting this value from guest OS(windows 10), can anybody knows how to do that?

BTW, the client can only run this application on a virtual machine which does not have internet connection, this is why I want to find and use unique identifier of virtual machine to license application.

I have tried many fingerprints of hardware in virtual machine, but I found those fingerprints can be easily copied by just copying the whole virtual machine, so I gave up these methods and finally found that uuid.locaion was the unchangeable identifier that I want.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [HERE](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-11/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-533B2C4F-7BD5-41EB-8392-2B9FE687AE50.html), you can use the smBIOS to get the UUID.

In Ubuntu use:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 1
...
Serial Number: VMware-56 4d e....
...
```

In Windows use the WMI object (recommended to use the CIM instance):

```
(Get-CimInstance Win32_Bios).SerialNumber
Serial Number: VMware-56 4d e....
```